# Gamma matrices in curved spacetime

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, covariance, dirac-matrices, qft-in-curved-spacetime

How to raise and lower indices of gamma matrix in curved spacetime? Do we raise and lower the index of gamma matrix with $ g_{\mu \nu} $?

Answer (score 2):

Gamma matrices with flat (curved) indices are raised & lowered with the flat (curved) metric, respectively.

Comment: Bigger question would be how to construct gamma matrices with curved indices....

Comment: Yes. One should then multiply with the vielbein (or its inverse).